# MVC: using HttpPostedFileBase returns NULL

Tags: model-view-controller, httppostedfilebase

I am trying to include file upload by it remains NULL  all the time. Here is my Model:

```
   [Display(Name = "Upload Document")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload), FileSize(102400)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase PathwaysToImpactUploadDocument { get; set; }
```

My View:
ProjectForm.cshtml

```
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PathwaysToImpactUploadDocument)
```

Upload.cshtml

```
@model HttpPostedFileBase

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Html.TextBox("", null, new {@class = "form-control", type = "file"})
@Html.ValidationMessage("")
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult New(ProjectCreateViewModel model){
}
```

But the **model.PathwaysToImpactUploadDocument** is always NULL. What am I missing?

Comment: How are you uploading the file - standard submit (have you included the `enctype` attribute in the form) or ajax?

Comment: I needed to add the enctype, you are correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that seem suspect here:

1. it appears that there is no form tag or submit button (may or may not be a problem) in your view
2. The model for your view is not the model for your action method

I would make sure your view looks something like:

```
@model ProjectCreateViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file, new {@class = "form-control", type = "file"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.file)
    <input type="submit">Upload</input>
}
```

Comment: I double checked and found out that the view is the problem, it does not have enctype = "multipart/form-data" declared. Thank you! I can now move forward to the logic of saving and downloading the file.